# Chart not generated from vba code unless another chart already exists

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have a table in excel with multiple columns and rows. I have written this simple code to generate a Line chart from my table:

```
Sub DrawLine()
   Dim cht As ChartObject
   For Each cht In Worksheets(Sheets.Count).ChartObjects
     cht.Chart.Type = xlLine
   Next cht
End Sub
```

However, when I execute this code I can't see my chart, unless if I have another chart on my worksheet generated manually. In this case, when I execute the code, the chart changes to display what my sub is doing.

Does anyone know what could be the problem ?

Comment: Your code has no calls to create a chart - it just operates on existing charts.

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating any charts with your code. What you're doing is changing any chart currently there to become a line chart.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things missing in your code. Pl see example below.

```
  Sub Test()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim ShName As String
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng1 = .Range("A2:A" & LastRow & ", B2:B" & LastRow)
        ShName = .Name

    End With
    Charts.Add
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .SetSourceData Source:=Rng1
        .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ShName
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]